# Need to parse mime content

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, mimekit

I have a Base-64 encoded string of the mime content of an email. The email itself contains a .p7m attachment.

Is it possible to use Mimekit to parse the mime content and extract the attachment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you have just a subset of the message (i.e. the base64 encoded content of one of the MIME parts).

If all you want to do is to get the raw `smime.p7m` file attachment (which is what is inside of the base64 blob that you have), then all you really need to do is call `File.WriteAllBytes ("smime.p7m", Convert.FromBase64String(base64))`.

But if you want to perform some action (such as decrypting or verifying the signature), then you'll need to get the [ApplicationPkcs7Mime](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_Cryptography_ApplicationPkcs7Mime.htm) representation:

```
ApplicationPkcs7Mime pkcs7;

using (var stream = new MemoryStream ()) {
    byte[] buffer;

    // write the Content-Type header
    buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes ("Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; name=smime.p7m\r\n");
    stream.Write (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    // write the Content-Type header
    buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes ("Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; name=smime.p7m\r\n");
    stream.Write (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    // write the header termination sequence
    buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes ("\r\n");
    stream.Write (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    // write the base64 encoded content
    buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (base64);
    stream.Write (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    // rewind the stream
    stream.Position = 0;

    pkcs7 = (ApplicationPkcs7Mime) MimeEntity.Load (stream);
}
```

Now all of the ApplicationPkcs7Mime API's are available for you to use.

Comment: It's not a subset of the message, it's the mime content of the entire message. I'm using EWS to obtain the mime content of the email message from the exchange server. What I need to do is parse this content, and then get the .p7m attachment from it.

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make any sense unless you mean exactly what I described.

Comment: Maybe I'm not describing it correctly.  In EWS, when I retrieve an email item, there is a field in the xml response called "mimecontent". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/mimecontent. This is basically a base-64 encoded string, of what I think is the entire message in mime format. So basically, what I'm trying to do is parse this string, and extract the individual fields, e.g. body text, attachments etc... Hope it makes a bit more sense now?

Comment: Base64 decide it. What do you get?

Comment: It looks like there some text in it with my email address and other info. As well as a lot of garbage.

Comment: Does it have headers? If so, create a stream based on the decoded base64 content and then use MimeMessage.Load().